# How to do docker load from bitbucket repository with shell

Tags: bash, docker, bamboo

I'm building a pipeline on bamboo that checkout from bitbucket repository, and then load the image from tar file and then push it into Azure container registry, but failed to build the pipeline with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -x

az login --service-principal \
    --username ${bamboo.az_sp_id} \
    --password ${bamboo.az_sp_password} \
    --tenant ${bamboo.az_sp_tenant}

az acr login -n ${bamboo.acr_repository} 
  
docker image load -i ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/ifhc/front-end/aia-presales-frontend-sit.tar

#docker save frontend > ifhc/front-end/aia-presales-frontend-sit.tar 
docker tag ${bamboo.acr_repository}/frontend:v${bamboo.buildNumber} 
docker push ${bamboo.acr_repository}/frontend:v${bamboo.buildNumber}
```

The error logs :

> docker image load -i
> /apps/atlassian/bamboo/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/196609/IH-IH-IH/ifhc/front-end/aia-presales-frontend-sit.tar
>
> open /apps/atlassian/bamboo/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/196609/IH-IH-IH/ifhc/front-end/aia-presales-frontend-sit.tar:
> no such file or directory

the path/url to tar file is as follow :

> bitbucket/projects/IFHC/repos/ifhc/browse/front-end/aia-presales-frontend-sit.tar

please any help/hint would be very appreciated, thank you

Comment: `bamboo.az_sp_id` is an illegal variable name. While environment variable names can legally contain any character except NUL, bash variables are not allowed to contain a dot.

Comment: @user1934428 ok i'll changed it , thank you. Any suggestion about how to load said tar file?

Comment: Please edit your posting to reflect the changes. With your docker question, I can't help you, since I have never used docker by myself.